# How can I control the max header size with CRACO like I can with the react-scripts --max-http-header-size=77777 in package.json start script?

Tags: reactjs, .net, create-react-app, craco

I've added CRACO to my create-react-app but it was using in package.json

```
"start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts --max-http-header-size=77777 start",
```

and now it's using

```
"start": "rimraf ./build && craco start",
```

How can I ensure a max http header size with CRACO like I did when using react-scripts?

CRACO is working great for allowing me to easily use Webpack Bundle Analyzer just by using npm run report by let me inject the appropriate changes into webpack.console.js, but this is the one and only issue I've run into so far.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!